# How to move a Div Up in mobile and below in Desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]There are 3 divs in a mai div. For desktop, the divs need to be appeared as prod-det, Color-det and price-det, However, in mobile, the divs should be Price-det, Prod-det and then Color-det.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
<div class="row prod-detail-list">
   <div class="col-md-5 prod-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Product Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Material Type</label> <span class="proVariant">PVC</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color</label><span class="proVariant">C100079</span>  
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Gloss Level</label><span class="proVariant">9-14</span> 
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Coil</label><span class="proVariant">300 FT PER COIL</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Box</label><span class="proVariant">2 COIL PER BOX</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Palette</label><span class="proVariant">10 BOX PER PALLET</span>   
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Size</label><span class="proVariant">1-3/8 X 3MM</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Embossing</label><span class="proVariant">20</span> 
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7 color-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Color Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color Type</label><span class="proVariant">Solid Colors</span>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7 price-det">
      <label>Product1</label>
      <input type="number" />
      <span class="price-amt"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Attached Desktop and Mobile design]

Answer (score 0):

Please change some order of the divs make price-det div the first then prod-det then price-det.

Add float right to price-det and remove the float right property on mobile.

Hope so it will work for you. If you share the design screenshot for this section then my answer will be more accurate.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/77853

Also the above link will be helpful for you I think.

Comment: have attached the design in the question. Also in mobile Prod-det, color-det should come in accordian...

Answer (score 0):

Here I used `visible-xs` and `hidden-xs` div to make this order on mobile.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="row prod-detail-list">
   <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
      <label>Product1</label>
      <input type="number" />
      <span class="price-amt"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 prod-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Product Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Material Type</label> <span class="proVariant">PVC</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color</label><span class="proVariant">C100079</span>  
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Gloss Level</label><span class="proVariant">9-14</span> 
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Coil</label><span class="proVariant">300 FT PER COIL</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Box</label><span class="proVariant">2 COIL PER BOX</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Palette</label><span class="proVariant">10 BOX PER PALLET</span>   
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Size</label><span class="proVariant">1-3/8 X 3MM</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Embossing</label><span class="proVariant">20</span> 
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 color-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Color Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color Type</label><span class="proVariant">Solid Colors</span>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden-xs col-md-7 price-det">
      <label>Product1</label>
      <input type="number" />
      <span class="price-amt"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here you can use just `@media` for mobile order:
Check this please...

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.prod-detail-list {
position: relative;
padding-top: 28px;
}
.price-det {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="row prod-detail-list">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 prod-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Product Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Material Type</label> <span class="proVariant">PVC</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color</label><span class="proVariant">C100079</span>  
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Gloss Level</label><span class="proVariant">9-14</span> 
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Coil</label><span class="proVariant">300 FT PER COIL</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Box</label><span class="proVariant">2 COIL PER BOX</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Palette</label><span class="proVariant">10 BOX PER PALLET</span>   
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Size</label><span class="proVariant">1-3/8 X 3MM</span>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Embossing</label><span class="proVariant">20</span> 
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 color-det">
      <h3 class="product-details">Color Details</h3>
      <h5 class="attr">
         <label>Color Type</label><span class="proVariant">Solid Colors</span>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 price-det">
      <label>Product1</label>
      <input type="number" />
      <span class="price-amt"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can apply this class, however the values are coming from back-end and I am fetching the HTML in a framework which cannot be duplicated. Have shared you the screens .. Help me in other way. Thanks.

Comment: I understood @passionFinder Here I update answer check please